# how to send image name in database using multer and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, multer

When I'm trying to upload a photo with **`multer`** and **`express`**, everything is OK. But I'm not able to send the image name in `mongoose` database.

The images are uploaded successfully in the `upload` directory. I got the `imageUrl` in the body, but I'm not able to update the image name in `mongoose` database. However the other details are updated successfully.

Check the image below:

[image]

```js
//file upload using multer
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './uploads');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|png|JPEG)$/)) {
            var err = new Error();
            err.code = 'filetype';
            return callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
        }

    }
});
var upload = multer({
     storage: storage,
     limits: {
         fileSize: 1000000
     }
 }).single('userImage');
 app.patch('/updateProfile', authenticate, (req, res) => {
     upload(req, res, function(err) {
         var body = _.pick(req.body, ['name', 'email', 'mobile', 'imageUrl']);

         User.findOneAndUpdate({
             _id: req.user._id
         }, {
             $set: body
         }, {
             new: true
         }).then((user) => {
             if (!req.file) {
                 return res.send({
                     success: false,
                     msg: 'No file selected'
                 })
             }
             if (!user) {
                 res.status(404).send({
                     success: false,
                     msg: 'user not found'
                 })
             } else {
                 body.imageUrl = req.file.filename;
                 console.log(body)
                 res.send({
                     sucess: true,
                     msg: 'update sucessfully',
                     user
                 })
             }
         }).catch((err) => {
             res.send({
                 success: false,
                 msg: 'something wrong',
                 error: err
             });
         });
         if (err) {
             if (err.code === 'LIMIT_FILE_SIZE') {
                 return res.send({
                     success: false,
                     msg: 'limit file size 1MB '
                 })
             } else if (err.code === 'filetype') {
                 return res.send({
                     success: false,
                     msg: 'Must be valid file extension only jpg or png'
                 })
             } else {
                 return res.send({
                     success: false,
                     msg: 'something went wrong'
                 })
             }
         }

     });
 });
```

Comment: What is that body.imageurl?

Comment: body is a variable i have declare above

Comment: try this console.log(user) in the else part and let me know what it consoles

Comment: Above code is working i forget to add the field in model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({

    destination: function (req, file, callback) {

        callback(null, './images/post');

    },

    filename: function (req, file, callback) {

        if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|png|JPEG)$/)) {

            var err = new Error();

            err.code = 'filetype';

            return callback(err);

        } else {

            callback(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);

        }


    }

});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage, limits: { fileSize: 1000000 } }).single('imageUrl');

router.post('/posts',authenticate, (req, res) => {

    upload(req, res, function (err) {

        if (err) {

            if (err.code === 'LIMIT_FILE_SIZE') {

                return res.send({ success: false, msg: 'limit file size 1MB ' })

            } else if (err.code === 'filetype') {

                return res.send({ success: false, msg: 'Must be valid file extension only jpg or png' })

            } else {

                return res.send({ success: false, msg: 'something went wrong' })

            }

        } else {

            if (!req.file) {

                return res.send({ success: false, msg: 'No file selected' })

            }

            var post = new Post({

                heading: req.body.heading,

                body: req.body.body,

                imageUrl: req.file.filename,

                creator:req.user.id,

            });

            post.save().then((result) => {

                res.send({ post: result, sucess: true, msg: 'Post created' });

            }).catch((err) => {

                res.send({ sucess: false, msg: 'post not created', error: err })

            });

        }

    });


});
```